# restore eclipse project to a fixed point in the past

Tags: eclipse

**How can I get an eclipse java project to revert to the state it was in at a fixed point in the past?**  For example, an hour ago.  The desired effect would be to cause all configurations and file changes, etc., to be reverted.

If I give too much context about why I want this, I am afraid that the context will distract from my question, which is how to roll back the state of a project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of an easy way to do this.

For short periods such a an hour you can use the Eclipse local history. Use the 'Replace with > Local History...' option in a file's right click menu to choose the version of the file which was active at the time. But this has to be done for each file and will be very time consuming.

To go back beyond the local history you will have to be using a source control system (such as SVN, Git, ...).

Comment: Thank you and +1 for taking the time to look into this.